# WinForms ShowDialog() - No modal dialog box opens

Tags: winforms, showdialog

I want to open a dialog as a Login-Box in my Explorer-NamespaceExtension. When I call ShowDialog() the first time the box opens but not as a modal dialog. I can click elements in the Explorer. If I close these dialog and open it again, it is a modal dialog and interaction with the Explorer isn`t possible. Thats what I want to achieve with the first open.

My idea is that I call the form first from the wrong thread. Thats the reason why I used the following code, but it doesn`t solve the problem :/

```
public delegate void myDelegate();

    public void ShowDialogThreadSave()
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            myDelegate d = new myDelegate(ShowDialogThreadSave);
            this.Invoke(d);
        }
        else
        {
            this.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

I hope you have an idea :-)
Thanks!

Edit:
The call is fired from a background class. I have 3 possibilities to login into the extension, so i encapsulated the call:

```
public bool LogIn()
        {
            bool connected = BackEnd.isConnected();

            if(loginDialog == null)
            {
                LogIn logIn = new LogIn();
            }
            else
            {
                if (!connected && !Utils.AlreadyLoggedIn() && !loginDialog.IsAccessible && !loginDialog.Visible)
                    loginDialog.ShowDialogThreadSave();
                else if (!connected && !Utils.AlreadyLoggedIn() && !loginDialog.Visible)
                    loginDialog.ShowDialogThreadSave();
                else if (!connected && !Utils.AlreadyLoggedIn() && loginDialog.Visible)
                    LOG.DebugFormat("error");
                else
                    Utils.ConnectWithoutLoginWindow();
            }
            connected = BackEnd.isConnected();

            return connected;
        }
```

Edit2: With debugging I found out that the ShowDialogThreadSave() is always called by the UI Thread and I will never use the if... What is the problem?

Comment: What is the context of the first call to this method? Could you show the code that run this method and where is located?

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: Where do you create `loginDialog`? (on the UI thread?) If `InvokeRequired` is false, this only tells you that you are in the same thread where it was created, not necessarily the UI thread (check Thread IDs). On a sidenote, `InvokeRequired` is always false everywhere before a form is shown.

Comment: @KekuSemau I create it in a class for handling the login. This class is called by a build in function and I don`t know if the UIThread calls it. How can I find out if it`s the UIThread?

Comment: I call the `loginDialog` outside the UI thread. Because of that I wanted to use `Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess()` and `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new System.Action(() => logInMethod()));` but my Application does not have a Current thread.